# Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /

Tags: php

Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in /home/haxcty/public_html/include/function.php on line 4 
Error

```
function lisencecheck() {
    if (substr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4 )  = 'www.') {
        substr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 4 );
        $domainame = ;
    } 
    else {
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $domainame = ;
    }    
    return $domainame;
}
```

Comment: `$domainame = ;` should be `$domainame = '';` i guess

Comment: Your code is full of mistakes. **1)** You're using `=` instead of `==` inside the `if` statement. **2)** You're not storing the results of `substr()` in a variable. **3)** `$domainame = ;`  is a syntax error. It should be `$domainame = '';`. **4)** `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];` alone doesn't mean *anything*. What do you want to do with it? Compare? Store it in a variable? You decide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how your code should be written (although, I'm not quite sure why you are returning a value if it is always empty or what this code is supposed to be doing):

```
function lisencecheck() {
    if (substr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4 ) == 'www.') {
        substr( $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 4 );
        $domainame = '';
    } 
    else {
        $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $domainame = '';
    }
    return $domainame;
}
```